# Creating new user with Smack 4.2.0-beta1 on ejabberd throws XMPP Exception: forbidden - auth

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd, smack

I am doing Chat application with smack . I am new for this technology.

I have created some manual users from Ejabberd server. Using those users I have done one to one chat and group chat.

But I tried to create new user from android code 
But I am getting this below error

```
 XMPPError: forbidden - auth
    08-02 08:23:36.273 31097-31097/com.agarangroup.hello W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketCollector.nextResultOrThrow(PacketCollector.java:232)
    08-02 08:23:36.273 31097-31097/com.agarangroup.hello W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketCollector.nextResultOrThrow(PacketCollector.java:207)
```

This is the configuration I have in ejabberd server

```
announce    [{allow,[{acl,admin}]}]
c2s [{deny,[{acl,blocked}]},{allow,[{acl,all}]}]
c2s_shaper  [{none,[{acl,admin}]},{normal,[all]}]
configure   [{allow,[{acl,admin}]}]
local   [{allow,[{acl,all}]}]
max_user_offline_messages   [{5000,[{acl,admin}]},{100,[all]}]
max_user_sessions   [{10,[all]}]
muc_create  [{allow,[{acl,all}]}]
pubsub_createnode   [{allow,[{acl,local}]}]
register    [{allow,[{acl,all}]}]
s2s_shaper  [{fast,[all]}]
trusted_network [{allow,[{acl,loopback}]}]
```

**Updated :**

**Here I am initialising my connection**

```
 private void initialiseConnection() {
        DomainBareJid serviceName = null;
        try {
            serviceName = JidCreate.domainBareFrom(ServiceAddress);
        } catch (XmppStringprepException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration
                .builder().setKeystoreType(null);
        // XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder().setKeystoreType(null);

        config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
        config.setServiceName(serviceName);
        config.setHost(serverAddress);
        config.setPort(5222);
        config.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
        XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementDefault(true);
        connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config.build());
        XMPPConnectionListener connectionListener = new XMPPConnectionListener();
        connection.addConnectionListener(connectionListener);
    }
```

**I am connection this connection after initialise**

```
 connection.connect();
                    DeliveryReceiptManager dm = DeliveryReceiptManager
                            .getInstanceFor(connection);
                    dm.setAutoReceiptMode(AutoReceiptMode.always);
                    dm.addReceiptReceivedListener(new ReceiptReceivedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onReceiptReceived(Jid fromJid, Jid toJid, String receiptId, Stanza receipt) {

                        }
                    });
                    connected = true;
```

**Method to create new user**

```
public void createNewUser(){
        try {
           /* UserRegisterUtil.registerAccount(connection,"Mathan","mathan@4792");
            connection.disconnect();
            connection.connect();*/
           Localpart lp = Localpart.from("IamHere");
            // Registering the user
            AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.getInstance(connection);
            accountManager.sensitiveOperationOverInsecureConnection(true);
            accountManager.createAccount(lp, "mathan123"); // Skipping optional fields like email, first name, last name, etc..
            Toast.makeText(context, "=>User creation completed....",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("xmpp", ">User creation completed....!");
        } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NotConnectedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SmackException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

It's an error I got It says Denied by ACL. But I don't know how to change  it in windows ejabberd server.

```
  <error code='403' type='auth'><forbidden xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/><text xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'>Denied by ACL</text></error>
```

**Can anyone tell me how to create a new user, What I wanna change in this configuration file?**

Also I have some doubt

**How to get offline messages in android using smack library?**

**How to get chat history?**

Answer (score 1):

About user creation: **you need to connect (not login) first to your connection**.

More, all username must be lowercase:

```
 accountManager.createAccount(lp.toLowerCase(), "mathan123");
```

---

About offline messages: they are dispatched when user will go online

About chat history: sorry, I don't have expirience with Ejabber, but for normal chat 1vs1 you probably need to store on client or add some custom feature on server (like Openfire).

Comment: I have connected to server already. Also I have changed the username in small letter still it says the same. :(

Comment: this sounds more like Ejabber + ACL (LDAP?) issue, however could be interesting to read the part when you connect to the server

Comment: Code seems good but I remark lowercase for usernames. Ejabber config probably has at least one error, has to be: (register, [{allow,,all}]) -> check this guide: https://www.ejabberd.im/files/doc/guide.html

Comment: I have changed the username in lowercase. Yeah

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to `/etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.yml`
2. Almost at the end of file, under `Section modules`, change `mod_register:ip_access:trusted_network` to `mod_register:ip_access:all`

Comment: new to stackoverflow. used different lines while typing but everything came on single line. "//almost at the end of file"  is a comment

Comment: Welcome to stackOverflow :-)