# The MUC configuration 'muc#roomconfig_roomowners' is not supported by the MUC service

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd, multiuserchat

I am working with xmpp and I want to create group chat. When I try to create group using the code below, I get the following error:

> The MUC configuration 'muc#roomconfig_roomowners' is not supported by the MUC service'.

Why do I get this error? Can anyone help me solve it?

Here is my code:

```
public void createGroupChat() {

    MultiUserChatManager manager = MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
    try {
        EntityBareJid jid = JidCreate.entityBareFrom(myroom@conference.servicename);

        MultiUserChat muc = manager.getMultiUserChat(jid);

        Set<Jid> owners = JidUtil.jidSetFrom(new String[]{"abc@servicename", "xyz@servicename"});

        Resourcepart nickname = Resourcepart.from("nickname");
        muc.create(nickname).getConfigFormManager().setRoomOwners(owners).submitConfigurationForm();

    } catch (XmppStringprepException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MultiUserChatException.MucAlreadyJoinedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MultiUserChatException.MissingMucCreationAcknowledgeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NotConnectedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MultiUserChatException.NotAMucServiceException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MultiUserChatException.MucConfigurationNotSupportedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

`

Comment: What XMPP server do you use?

Comment: own server @Rubycon

Comment: Please see my edited question

Comment: Ok, what XMPP lib do you use at your server?

Comment: Not getting your question.can you help me to uderstand it better?

Comment: I mean you build your own XMPP server totally from scratch using XMPP specs or you use some server-side xmpp libraries

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180328/discussion-between-d-g-and-rubycon).

Comment: i use ejabberd @Rubycon

Comment: Maybe it can help you, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38693928/getting-mucconfigurationnotsupportedexception-in-android-smack-4-2-0-beta1

Comment: @Rubycon i have tried the solution that you suggested in above link but I am getting error. form.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_roomowners", owners); says 'Couldn't find a field for the specified variable.' Can you hep me?

Comment: I have created new question https://stackoverflow.com/q/52512289/7473384 @Rubycon Can you halp me?

Answer (score 0):

> Why do I get this error?

Probably because the MUC service does not support the configuration option.

> Can anyone help me solve it?

By switching to a MUC service implementation which supports the option.

Comment: What is the meaning of 'By switching MUC service implimentation' ? Can you please explain me? because i m new to xmpp. i am using ejabberd .